# SwiftUI decoding JSON from API

Tags: json, swift, swiftui

I know there are already some articles regarding this issue, but I could not find anything related to my JSON.

This is how my JSON likes like:

```
{
  "message": {
    "affenpinscher": [],
    "african": [],
    "airedale": [],
    "akita": [],
    "appenzeller": [],
    "australian": [
      "shepherd"
    ],
    "basenji": []
  },
  "status: "succes"
}
```

So, if I understand it correctly it is dictionary because it starts with {, but what are the things inside the "message"?

This is my Dog.swift class where I am re-writing the JSON, but I am not sure if it is correct:

```
class Dog: Decodable, Identifiable {
    
    var message: Message?
    var status: String?
}

struct Message: Decodable {
    
    var affenpinscher: [String:[String]]?
    var african: [String]?
    var airedale: [String]?
    var akita: [String]?
    var appenzeller: [String]?
    var australian: [String]?
    var basenji: [String]?
}
```

As you can see in the first value I was trying to play with data types, but no success.

I am decoding and parsing JSON here:

```
class ContentModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var dogs = Message()
    
    init() {
        getDogs()
    }
    
    func getDogs(){
        
        // Create URL
        let urlString = Constants.apiUrl
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        
        if let url = url {
            // Create URL request
            var request = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 10)
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
             
            // Get URLSession
            let session = URLSession.shared
            
            // Create Data Task
            let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                // Check that there is not an error
                if error == nil {
                    
                    do {
                        // Parse JSON
                        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                        let result = try decoder.decode(Dog.self, from: data!)
                        print(result)
                        
                        // Assign result to the dogs property
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.dogs = result.message!
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            // Start the Data Task
            dataTask.resume()
        }
    }
    
}
```

And here I would love to iterate through it eventually, which I also have no idea how to do it:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var model: ContentModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack {
                    if model.dogs != nil {
//                        ForEach(Array(model.dogs.keys), id: \.self) { d in
//                            Text(d)
//                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("All Dogs")
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

What can I try next to resolve this?

Comment: Don’t make properties optional by default, only make them that if they actually can be nil. And we can’t really help you with how  Message should be declared since it’s content isn’t clear from the given json.

Comment: If we assume that in message that the values for each key is a string array then I wouldn’t create separate properties but just decode the whole message as a dictionary, `let message: [String: [String]]` (in `Dogs`) and then convert it into something more useful in a later step

Comment: Hi @JoakimDanielson, to your first comment.
when I put the api url to website I can see something like this: 
"message":
 "australian":
       0: "sheppard"

I will post a screenshot as well in my question above, so it is more clear what I mean.

To your second comment. I think that is a good idea too. I can try that too!

Comment: @JoakimDanielson also when I make message:[String:[String]] then in my ContentModel.swift in DispatchQueue where I am assigning self.dogs = result.message! now I should I have self.dog = [result:result.message!] ? Because this is confusing me a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all don't use classes for a JSON model and to conform to `Identifiable` you have to add an `id` property and `CodingKeys` if there is no key `id` in the JSON.

My suggestion is to map the unhandy `[String: [String]]` dictionary to an array of an extra struct

I renamed `Dog` as `Response` and named the extra struct `Dog`

```
struct Dog {
    let name : String
    let types : [String]
}

struct Response: Decodable, Identifiable {
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case message, status }
    let id = UUID()
    
    let dogs: [Dog]
    let status: String
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        status = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .status)
        let message = try container.decode([String:[String]].self, forKey: .message)
        dogs = message.map(Dog.init).sorted{$0.name < $1.name}
    }
}
```

In the model declare

```
@Published var dogs = [Dog]()
```

and decode

```
let result = try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: data!)
print(result)

// Assign result to the dogs property
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.dogs = result.dogs
}
```

The `dogs` array can be displayed seamlessly in a `List`

---

PS: Actually `appenzeller` is supposed to be

```
"appenzeller": ["sennenhund"],
```

or correctly in English

```
 "appenzell": ["mountain dog"],
```

Comment: Thanks Vadian, 
It helps a lot. It is very different approach and very experienced for me haha. I will need to study what you did there for couple of hours I guess...but I am getting no errors now and it prints into console all the dogs now.

Now, I just need to print them in my UI somehow :O Is there any different way how to display them in the List?

Comment: You don't need `if model.dogs != nil` because the array is non-optional. Delete the `if` expression. Just iterate the array and display `ForEach(model.dogs) { dog in Text(dog.name)`

Comment: Yes, I figure that out! 

Hmm, I can see the dog names in the console, but not in the UI, haha. So, weird.

Comment: Fixed it! There was a problem in my List.
THanks a lot!

Comment: By the way Vadia, is there a way how to do it like I initially wanted? Declaring every single breed etc...? I would like to know that too

Comment: Yes, it is, but you will get a huge static object. My suggestion is much more efficient because it's dynamic.

Comment: I understand. I am just thinking for example how can I for example now get access to the message value. For example if I want to display pictures just of that specific breed of dog.

Comment: The `Dog` array represents the `message` value.

Comment: I think I am just confused, because I never used this approach..but I have no success accessing it.

Comment: Hi Vadian, I don't want to use your time so much, but do you think you would be able to demonstrate for my learning purposes how would you structure my Dog class and Message struct as I did initially with how would you decode it later? 

I understand your approach is much better, but it is too complicated for me to understand and to move on and use it later. I have no idea how to access the message property from the Dog array...and I have tried for hours :/ 

Thanks in advance! It means a lot

Comment: Why do you like to prefer a tedious way over an efficient one? The (JSON) model is pretty easy: The `message` dictionary is a collection of key/value pairs, a key is the breed's name and the value is an array of types.  In my suggested model each key/value pair represents one `Dog` instance, the key is `name` and the value is `types`. In a SwifUI view a dictionary is inappropriate. You have to strip the keys, sort them and get each value by key. This is unnecessarily expensive. Tables in SwiftUI (end even UIKit) rely on arrays.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I would not prefer that way. It's just I am new to this and it is really hard for me to understand your way of approach. Therefore, it is really hard for me to understand what is going on and how can I for example access those values from that Dog instance by using key/value pairs + stripping it down to keys and sorting them, this just adds up on difficulty, which I don't understand at the beginning already....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241977/discussion-between-peter-mihok-and-vadian).

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't support this inefficient dictionary way. Please take my suggestion or leave it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the native Swift approach that @vadian [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71095196/7117009) is a much lighter weight solution, but if you work with JSON often I'd recommend using [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON).

You can parse the URL data task response into a Swifty json object like so:

```swift
import SwiftyJSON

guard let data = data, let json = try? JSON(data: data) else {
    return
}

// Make sure the json fetch was successful 
if json["status"].stringValue != "success" {
   return
}
```

Then you can access the message object safely without the verbosity of using Decodable. Here the message is parsed into an array of dog structs:

```swift
struct Dog {
    let name : String
    let types : [String]
}

var dogs: [Dog] = []

/// Load the docs into an array
for (name, typesJson) in json["message"].dictionaryValue {
    dogs.append(Dog(name: name, types: typesJson.arrayValue.map { $0.stringValue }))
}

print("dogs", dogs)
```